# How do I suppress an argument when nothing is input on command line?

Tags: python, argparse

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--selection', '-s')
parser.add_argument('--choice', '-c', default = argparse.SUPPRESS)
args = parser.parse_args()

def main(selection, choice):
    print(selection)
    print(choice)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main(args.selection, args.choice)
```

The example provided is just to provide something simple and short that accurately articulates the actual problem I am facing in my project. My goal is to be able to ignore an argument within the code body when it is NOT typed into the terminal. I would like to be able to do this through passing the argument as a parameter for a function. I based my code off of searching 'suppress' in the following link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

When I run the code as is with the terminal input looking like so: `python3 stackquestion.py -s cheese`, I receive the following error on the line where the function is called:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

I've tried adding the following parameter into parser like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

I've also tried the above with

```
parser.add_argument('--choice', '-c')
```

But I get the same issue on the same line.

@Barmar answered this question in the comments. Using 'default = None' in parser.add_argument works fine; The code runs without any errors. I selected the anser from @BorrajaX because it's a simple solution to my problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you want: do you want to ignore an explicitly passed argument? If so, why?

Comment: `SUPPRESS` means that it doesn't create `args.choice` if the option isn't provided. What are you expecting to pass to `main()` in that case? Why not use something like `default=None`?

Comment: In line with Barmar's comment -- the error `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'choice'` is what you're _asking_ Python to do. You're getting what you're asking for; if you don't want it, stop asking for it.

Comment: `main()` never even uses its `choice` parameter, so what's the point of that command-line argument anyway?

Comment: @wjandrea The code I provided is a condensed example of what I am actually doing. I wanted to provide a clear, and simple example that I felt would accurately depict my problem; therefor being able to get an answer that can help solve the bigger issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: @dvines Well, what I'm saying is it's not clear. Why does `main()` have a `choice` parameter if it's unused?

Comment: BTW, `default=None` is the default, so you can just leave that off.

Comment: Okay I edited it. I was unware of 'None' already being default. At this point I suppose I can use a simple 'if' statement to prevent 'None' from being printed to terminal, or is there another way to avoid this?

Comment: @dvines Something like `if args.choice is not None: print(choice)` should work fine, like in BorrajaX's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#default):

> Providing `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` causes **no attribute to be added** if the command-line argument was not present:

But you're still assuming it will be there by using it in the call to `main`:

```
main(args.selection, args.choice)
```

A suppressed argument won't be there (i.e. there won't be an `args.choice` in the arguments) unless the caller **specifically** called your script adding `--choice="something"`. If this doesn't happen, `args.choice` doesn't exist.

If you really want to use `SUPPRESS`, you're going to have to check whether the argument is in the `args` Namespace by doing `if 'choice' in args:` and operate accordingly.

Another option (probably more common) can be using a specific... thing (normally the value `None`, which is what argparse uses by default, anyway) to be used as a default, and `if args.choice is None`, then assume it hasn't been provided by the user.

Maybe you could look at this the other way around: You want to ensure `selection` is provided and leave `choice` as optional?

You can try to set up the arguments like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--selection', '-s', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--choice', '-c')
args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if args.choice is None:
        print("No choice provided")
    else:
        print(f"Oh, the user provided choice and it's: {args.choice}")

    print(f"And selection HAS TO BE THERE, right? {args.selection}")
```

Comment: I simply want to allow the option of 'choice'. If the user doesn't use the 'choice' option, then I want the program to run without the 'choice' argument; choice has no detrimental affect on the program. If the user DOES want choice, then it is include where 'choice' is being called. I was unaware that 'None' was the default 'default'.

Comment: This is a good answer except for the required optional argument. (Even the name is self-contradictory.) See [this SO question](/q/24180527/4518341). If I were you, I'd make it a positional argument instead.